# Python Tkinter destroy label after the click of a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a label which appears after the click of a button, however after each click of the button the previous label remains in its position and a new one is created, I would like for the new label to be put in place of the old one, the code is below:

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get('http://www.ipvoid.com/ip-blacklist-check/')

def helloCallBack():
   ip = entry.get()
   elem = browser.find_element_by_name('ip')  # Find the search box
   elem.send_keys(ip + Keys.RETURN)
   for elem in itertools.chain(browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "label label-success"]'), browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class = "label label-danger"]')):
      print elem.text
   label2 = tk.Label(root1, text="IPVoid: " + elem.text)
   label2.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

root1 = tk.Tk()
root1.geometry("500x500")
root1.title("CZEKER")
label = tk.Label(root1, text='Input IP Address:') 
entry = tk.Entry(root1)
label.pack(side=tk.TOP)
entry.pack()
B = tk.Button(root1, text = "Analiza", command = helloCallBack)
B.pack()
label2 = tk.Label(root1, text="IPVoid: " + elem.text)
label2.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

root1.mainloop()
```

I think i'm not quite sure how this loop works, whenever button B is clicked, the program executes method helloCallBack(), in which label2 is populated. However i cannot destroy the label at the beginning of the method since it hasn't been populated yet, but i can't destroy it after either, because it would immediately destroy it after it appears, not the moment button B would be clicked a second time. My question is as follows: How can i make a new label2 appear in place of the old label2 after each click of button B. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of recreating that label every click, you can create it with empty text then change its content on every click.

```
def helloCallBack():
    ...
    ...
    label2.configure(text="IPVoid: " + elem.text)

label2 = tk.Label(root1, text="") 
#or just label2 = tk.Label(root1) used that one to make it explicit right now
label2.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
```