# tkinter python3 clearing text

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a little game for my kiddo and I just got around to putting it into tkinter. I've spent a long time trying to see if just removing text is possible which the methods I've found weren't what I needed (i.e. delete()). Currently, it works, it just keeps returning text on new lines vertically so it gets really long.

```
alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s",
"t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

win = ["Good work! Let's go again.", "Way to go. Your hard work is paying off!", "Good attention for detail!"]
oops = ["Opps. Keep trying! You'll get it next time.", "That's not right but nice try! Keep working at it."]

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):

        self.master.title("Learning is fun!")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        mathButton = Button(self, text="Numbers", command=self.math)
        letterButton = Button(self, text="Letters", command=self.alphafun)

        mathButton.place(x=50, y=250)
        letterButton.place(x=250, y=250)

    def alphafun(self):

        self.x = random.choice(alphabet)
        text = Label(self, text=f"Type this letter: {self.x}")
        text.pack()

        self.user_input = StringVar()
        prompt = ttk.Entry(width=14, textvariable=self.user_input)
        prompt.place(x=150, y=200)

        submitButton = Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.alphacheck)
        submitButton.place(x=255, y=200)
        submitButton.bind("<Return>", func=self.alphacheck)

    def alphacheck(self):

        if self.user_input.get() == self.x:
            text = Label(self, text=f"\n{random.choice(win)}")
            text.pack()
            self.alphafun()
        else:
            text = Label(self, text=f"\n{random.choice(oops)}")
            text.pack()
            self.alphafun()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

There is a math function I left out for brevity.

I would like the window to clear the text, essentially just returning what the screen looks like with the init_window but also rerunning the alphafun function.

Attempts:

self.destroy() - destroys the whole frame (including widgets)

self.update() - at the beginning of alphafun and after alphacheck

self.destroy() after creating a separate create_widget function

```
    def create_widgets(self):

        mathButton = Button(self, text="Numbers", command=self.math)
        letterButton = Button(self, text="Letters", command=self.alphafun)

        mathButton.place(x=50, y=250)
        letterButton.place(x=250, y=250)

    def init_window(self):

        self.master.title("Learning is fun!")
        # Style().configure("TFrame", background="#333")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.create_widgets()

    def alphafun(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.create_widgets()
```

=====================EDIT WITH SOLUTION:

So I created a label in the init_window:

```
def init_window(self):

    self.master.title("Learning is fun!")
    Style().configure("TFrame", background="#93F")
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    mathButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Numbers", command=self.math)
    # mathButton.config(bg="white")
    letterButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Letters", command=self.alphafun)

    mathButton.place(x=50, y=250)
    letterButton.place(x=250, y=250)

    ### The question label
    self.label_question = Label(self, text = '')
    self.label_question.place(x=150, y=0)
    self.label_question.pack()
    self.label_question.configure(font=("Courier", 16), background='#93F')

    ### The answer label
    self.label_answer = Label(self, text='')
    self.label_answer.place(x=150, y=50)
    self.label_answer.pack()
    self.label_answer.configure(font=("Courier", 10), background='#93F')
```

And after it checks the answer, it updates the corresponding label:

```
    if self.user_input.get() == self.x:
        ### updates the label_answer Label in the above code
        self.label_answer.configure(text = f"\n{random.choice(win)}")
        self.correct_answers += 1
        ### and because of the SO help, I could add a counter for correct guesses too (label not shown above, but it's the same as the other two)
        self.label_counter.configure(text=f"Correct answers: {self.correct_answers}")
        self.alphafun()
```

and here updates the question label:

```
def alphafun(self):
    self.x = random.choice(alphabet)
    ### Right here, updates the corresponding label
    self.label_question.configure(text=f"Type this letter: {self.x}")
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried. If you're wanting to remove label widgets, using the `delete` method is the way to accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, updated with some of the things I've tried.

Comment: You are re-creating that Label every time, which seems unnecessary. Create an empty Label in init, then change its content as you like. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46687436/3134251

Comment: Please provide to isolate your issue using by creating a [mcve].

Comment: Apologies for the poor question, however, @Lafexlos link was very helpful. That code did what I needed it to do.

Comment: @johnnycodes Perhaps consider answering.